# what's wrong with my higher order procedure?

Tags: scheme

I can't figure out why my lambda is wrong. It should create a make-exp.

```
(define (exp b n)
    (if (n = 0) 
        1
        (* b (exp b (- n 1)))))

(define make-exp (lambda(n) (lambda(b)(exp b n ))))

(define square (make-exp 2))

(square 3)
```

Error: 2 is not a function [square, exp, (anon)]

Answer (score 5):

```
(n = 0)
```

This calls the function `n` with the arguments `=` and `0`, except `n` is `2` and not a function, so this does not work. Presumably you meant `(= n 0)`.